# Unable to accept multiple commandline arguments into one variable within expect

Tags: scripting, expect

Using cygwin 32bit, expect v5.45 (what comes with the latest cygwin, it seems).

```
COMMAND="$WIN_BUILD_ROOT\\scripts\\signBinaries.bat $BUS $NET_DRIVE $WIN_SIGNING_ROOT"
$CLIENT_BUILD_ROOT/scripts/runCommand.sh $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $COMMAND
```

runCommand.sh:

```
#!C:\cygwin\bin\expect.exe -f
set timeout 9

set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]
set arg3 [lindex $argv 2]
set arg4 [lindex $argv 3]
set COMMAND [lrange $argv 4 end]

send -- "$COMMAND\r"
```

Gives me:

```
{s:\git\builds\scripts\signBinaries.bat} 64 s {s:\git\builds\}
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The scenario is, the first four arguments are fixed. There could then be a variable number of commands following those, which I want to have as one command to be executed by expect. If I just use `[lindex argv 4]`, I only get the `signBinaries` script name, whether or not it's enclosed in quotes.  Using `lrange` (found via googling) instead, it's enclosing the string arguments in braces, as shown.  Why would it be modifying my arguments in this fashion and how do I fix it so that `$COMMAND` contains the command as I intended it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  Figured it out:

```
set COMMAND [join [lrange $argv 4 end]]
```

Gives me:

```
s:\git\builds\scripts\signBinaries.bat 64 s s:\git\builds
"BUS: 64"
"DRIVE: s"
"WORKSPACE: s:\git\builds"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl, which expect extends, you have to be aware of the datatype of your variables: is it a string or a list? When a list gets stringified, it may quote some of its elements if they contain "metacharacters" (like backslash and braces).

In most cases when you want to use the contents of a list as a single string, it's best to stringify it yourself:

```
set COMMAND [list "s:\\git\\builds\\scripts\\signBinaries.bat" 64 s "s:\\git\\builds\\"]

puts $COMMAND
# => {s:\git\builds\scripts\signBinaries.bat} 64 s s:\\git\\builds\\

puts [join $COMMAND " "]
# => s:\git\builds\scripts\signBinaries.bat 64 s s:\git\builds\
```